# Highlight match in a table vs a vector

Tags: excel

I have a series of number in excel:

```
 1    1  1  
 2    3  3
 3    4  2
 4    2  4
```

I would like to highlight some of them if they match the leading column value: i.e. for the example I gave, I would like to highlight the bolded values

```
 1    **1**  **1**  
 2      3      3
 3      4      2
 4      2    **4**
```

Comment: Did you try conditional formatting? If you did, where are you stuck?

Comment: Jerry, conditional formatting is good if I want to compare one value vs a list here I have a list of values I want to compare vs a table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with conditional formatting:

1. Highlight the range to format and make sure the topmost, leftmost cell is the active one (it's lighter than the other highlighted cells.
2. Create a new formatting rule with the formula and formatting of your choice:

   ```
   =$A1=B1
   ```

[image]

And click 'OK':

[image]

---

When you put this formula in, it compares the B1 cell to the A1 cell. If they are equal, the formatting applies.

In C1, you will have the C1 cell compared with the A1 cell (it remains A1 because the column is locked with the `$` sign)

In B2, you get B2 and A2 compared (the row of A1 was not locked, so the row changes relative to the cell you're moving to) and so on for the other cells.